# FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION dosen´t work on Android 4.4

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application then when compile for android 8.0 works perfectly,get the notification in the notification center of the mobile..

But if compile for android 4.4 doesn't work ,(do not get the notification)

used this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging

Code => 
https://github.com/franciscom95/FcmXamarinTest

Answer (score 0):

try going through the below code hope this helps you and i am currently using like this.

```
public void showNotification(String message, String title, String action, String value, boolean isImageUrl, String CHANNEL_ID, String BADGE_NUMBER) throws CleverTapPermissionsNotSatisfied, CleverTapMetaDataNotFoundException {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
        if (notification_key_values.containsKey(action.toLowerCase())) {
            mainIntent.putExtra("FromPushNotification", true);
            mainIntent.putExtra("PushAction", action);
            if (!isImageUrl) {
                String hash_value = notification_key_values.get(action.toLowerCase());
                if (!hash_value.isEmpty()) {
                    updateNotification(message, hash_value, action, value, extras.getString("TokenId"), extras.getString("SegmentId"), extras.getString("Action"));
                }
            }
            if (action.toLowerCase().equals("redirectionurl")) {
                mainIntent.putExtra("PushValue", value);
            }
        } else {
            if (!isImageUrl) {
                updateNotification(message, action, action, value, "", "", "");
                mainIntent.putExtra("FromPushNotification", true);
                mainIntent.putExtra("PushAction", action);
            } else {
                mainIntent.putExtra("FromPushNotification", false);
            }
        }
        mainIntent.putExtras(extras);
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);
        PendingIntent launchIntent;
        launchIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Notification notification;
        setLargeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.appicon);
        Uri notification_sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CleverTapAPI cleverTapAPI = CleverTapAPI.getInstance(this);
            cleverTapAPI.createNotificationChannel(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, " ", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH, false);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, this.CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon());
            builder.setLargeIcon(setLargeIcon);
            builder.setStyle(style);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(message);
            notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.contentIntent = launchIntent;
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            notificationManagerCompat.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(),notification );
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon())
                        .setLargeIcon(setLargeIcon)
                        .setContentTitle(
                                title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.position_blue))
                        .setStyle(style)
                        .setSound(notification_sound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();
            } else {
                notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon())
                        .setContentTitle(
                                title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setStyle(style)
                        .setSound(notification_sound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            }
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.contentIntent = launchIntent;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your answer it really helped but not the notification aren´t showing they make sound and vibrate but dosen´t show on notification center for kit kat 4.4, any suggestions.

Comment: It seems it doesnt work without an icon.
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon);